# Why does my code print out text and not the value of the variable?

Tags: php, global-variables

I'm just learning and experimenting. My test code prints out text instead of the value of the variable. i.e $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] not the value such as 192.xxx etc

I can display the value using echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] but when I try to combine 1st and 2nd part in a variable, it only prints text. The names are correct.

```
$query = $firstName . "[\"" . $secondName . "\"]";
echo $query;
```

It just displays the string, not the value of the variable.

Comment: Because you just __concatenating strings__.

Comment: So how would I get that to work? i.e print out the value and not the textual name? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I have **no idea** why you do this, here's a sample ([demo](https://3v4l.org/fpIJR)):

```
$firstName = '_SERVER'; // Note that `$firstName` has no `$`
$secondName = 'REMOTE_ADDR';

echo ${$firstName}[$secondName];
```

What you need to read is [**variable variables**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: Thanks, its just the last line I needed. As for why, I'm just practicing passing values from a form to a processing page. Its just experimenting.